# maintain forward slash in ios string

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I'm trying to do the following in xcode:

```
NSString *URL = @"http://someUrl/page.php";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
```

but I'm not sure if the forward slashes are maintained when they are in double quotes. I don't know what the rules are for ios characters in single/double quotes.

does the URL String remain exactly as was declared in the quotes?
thanks

Comment: go ahead and see what happens...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that, I've used that often without any problems. If you wanted the backslash (\), then you would have to escape it.

Comment: The question was on forward not on backward slash

Answer (score 3):

The string in your example will be exactly as you declared it. For reference, `\` is the escape character for strings in objective-c. If you want to use a backslash, you would then have to double it (e.g., `\\`).